# Checking whether a sequence of integers is increasing

Tags: c#

I'm stuck only partially passing the below problem.

Given a sequence of integers, check whether it is possible to obtain a strictly increasing sequence by erasing no more than one element from it.

Example

```
sequence = [1, 3, 2, 1]
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = false

sequence = [1, 3, 2]
almostIncreasingSequence(sequence) = true
```

My code that is only passing some examples:

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
   int seqIncreasing = 0;
    if (sequence.Length == 1) return true;
    for (int i = 0;i < sequence.Length-2;i++)
    {
        if ((sequence[i] == sequence[++i]+1)||(sequence[i] == sequence[++i])) 
        {
            seqIncreasing++; 
        } 
    } 
    return ((seqIncreasing == sequence.Length) || (--seqIncreasing == sequence.Length));
}
```

Failed Examples:

```
Input:
    sequence: [1, 3, 2]
Output:
    false
Expected Output:
    true

Input:
    sequence: [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Output:
    false
Expected Output:
    true

Input:
    sequence: [0, -2, 5, 6]
Output:
    false
Expected Output:
    true

Input:
    sequence: [1, 1]
Output:
    false
Expected Output:
    true
```

Comment: I think you are a bit abusing `++` and `--` operators. Can you try to get rid of them?

Comment: Stop using `++x` until you first know exactly what it does and how to properly use it.  To begin, remove all occurences of `++x` and your code might actually work.

Comment: Also probably you've understood the problem wrong. Take a look at this example [0, -2, 5, 6] where expected output is **true**. It is so because you can erase -2 receiving [0 5 6] which is increasing. I cannot see any `<`  or `>` comparison in your code, only `==`.

Answer (score 9):

The LINQ-based answer is fine, and expresses the basic problem well. It's easy to read and understand, and solves the problem directly. However, it does have the problem that it requires generating a new sequence for each element in the original. As the sequences get longer, this becomes dramatically more costly and eventually, intractable.

It doesn't help that it requires the use of `Skip()` and `Take()`, which themselves add to the overhead of handling the original sequence.

A different approach is to scan the sequence once, but keep track of whether a deletion has already been attempted and when finding an out-of-sequence element, to a) immediately return `false` if a deletion was already found, and b) don't include the deleted element in the determination of the sequence.

The code you tried *almost* accomplishes this. Here's a version that works:

```
static bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence)
{
    bool foundOne = false;

    for (int i = -1, j = 0, k = 1; k < sequence.Length; k++)
    {
        bool deleteCurrent = false;

        if (sequence[j] >= sequence[k])
        {
            if (foundOne)
            {
                return false;
            }
            foundOne = true;

            if (k > 1 && sequence[i] >= sequence[k])
            {
                deleteCurrent = true;
            }
        }

        if (!foundOne)
        {
            i = j;
        }

        if (!deleteCurrent)
        {
            j = k;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Note: I originally thought your attempt could be fixed with a minor change. But ultimately, it turned out that it had to be essentially the same as the generic implementation I wrote (especially once I fixed that one too…see below). The only material difference is really just whether one uses an array or a generic `IEnumerable<T>`.

For grins, I wrote another approach that is in the vein of the LINQ-based solution, in that it works on any sequence, not just arrays. I also made it generic (albeit with the constraint that the type implements `IComparable<T>`). That looks like this:

```
static bool almostIncreasingSequence<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    bool foundOne = false;
    int i = 0;
    T previous = default(T), previousPrevious = default(T);

    foreach (T t in sequence)
    {
        bool deleteCurrent = false;

        if (i > 0)
        {
            if (previous.CompareTo(t) >= 0)
            {
                if (foundOne)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                // So, which one do we delete? If the element before the previous
                // one is in sequence with the current element, delete the previous
                // element. If it's out of sequence with the current element, delete
                // the current element. If we don't have a previous previous element,
                // delete the previous one.

                if (i > 1 && previousPrevious.CompareTo(t) >= 0)
                {
                    deleteCurrent = true;
                }

                foundOne = true;
            }
        }

        if (!foundOne)
        {
            previousPrevious = previous;
        }

        if (!deleteCurrent)
        {
            previous = t;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Of course, if you're willing to copy the original sequence into a temporary array, if it's not already one, then you could easily make the array-based version generic, which would make the code a lot simpler but still generic. It just depends on what your priorities are.

**Addendum:**

The basic performance difference between the LINQ method and a linear method (such as mine above) is obvious, but I was curious and wanted to quantify this difference. So I ran some tests, using randomly generated sequences, to get a rough idea of the difference.

I performed two versions of the tests: the first, I ran a loop with 1000 trials, where the sequences could be anywhere between 10 and 100 elements long; and the second, with 10,000 trials and sequences between 100 and 1000 elements long. I performed the second version, because on my laptop the entire test of 1000 trials with shorter sequences completed in less than 1/20th of a second, too short a time for me to have confidence in the validity of the result.

With that first version, the code spent about 1ms calling the linear method of the check, and about 30ms calling the LINQ method, for a 30x difference in speed. Increasing the number of trials to 10,000 confirmed the result; the times scaled almost exactly 10x for each method, keeping a difference of 30x.

With the second version, the difference was closer to *400*x. The linear version took about 0.07 seconds, while the LINQ version took 30 seconds.

As expected, the longer the sequence, the worse the disparity. For very short sequences, not only is the code unlikely to ever spend much time in the sequence-checking logic, the discrepancy between the linear and LINQ methods is going to be relatively small. But as the sequences get longer, the discrepancy will trend to very poor performance for the LINQ version while the linear version remains an excellent performer.

The LINQ version is *very* readable and concise. So in a situation where the inputs are always going to be relatively short (on the order of a dozen or two elements at the most), I'd go with the LINQ version. But if I expected to execute this test routinely with data that was any longer than that, I would avoid the LINQ and stick with the much more efficient linear approach.

*A note on the randomly-generated sequences: I wrote the code to generate a monotonically increasing sequence of non-negative numbers, of the desired length, and then inserted between 0 and 2 (inclusive) new elements having a value of `int.MinValue` or `int.MaxValue` (also randomly selected, for each insertion). In this way, a third of the tests involved sequences that were trivially valid, a third involved sequences that required finding the correct single element to remove, and a third were not valid (i.e. did not meet the requirement that it could be made monotonically increasing by deleting at most one element).*

Comment: Nice in depth analysis.

Comment: It seems that your first example will give false negatives on any sequence with a bigger number nestled anywhere but the first spot in an otherwise increasing sequence. For example **[0, 1, 10, 2, 3]**. How would you fix that?

Comment: @Brad: see edit above. You are right, the previous code didn't work in scenarios such as you describe. I mistakenly only tested by inserting `-1`, a smaller number than the sequence overall. The above code will work whether the inserted number is smaller or larger.

Answer (score 2):

*UPDATE*: Fixed a bug related to the way I was generating subsequences using `Except`. The obvious issue was that the subsequences generated when the original sequence contained duplicate items could be wrong; all positions of duplicate items could be potentially removed.

This problem seems deceptively simple but you can easily get bogged down in loops with ifs and elses that will never get it exactly right.

The best way to solve this is to take a step back and understand what the condition you are asking for really means. An almost strictly increasing sequence is one such that, of all possible subsequences created be removing one single item, at least one must be strictly increasing.

Ok, that seems to be sound reasoning, and its easy to implement, so lets do it:

First, a trivial method that tells us if a given sequence is strictly increasing:

```
private static bool IsStrictlyIncreasing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    where T : IComparable<T>
{
    using (var e = sequence.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!e.MoveNext())
            return true;

        var previous = e.Current;

        while (e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (e.Current.CompareTo(previous) <= 0)
                return false;

            previous = e.Current;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now we need a helper method to generate all possible subsequences removing one item (as stated above, simply using `Except` will not cut it if `T` has value equality semantics):

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GenerateSubsequences<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    => Enumerable.Range(0, sequence.Count())
                 .Select(i => sequence.Take(i)
                                      .Concat(sequence.Skip(i + 1)))
```

And now, we simply need to check all subsequences and find at least one that is strictly increasing:

```
public static bool IsAlmostStrictlyIncreasing<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence)
    where T : IComparable<T>
    => sequence.GenerateSubsequences()
               .Any(s => s.IsStrictlyIncreasing());
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 2):

Having solved that [CodeSignal challenge using C#](https://app.codesignal.com/arcade/intro/level-2/2mxbGwLzvkTCKAJMG/solutions?solutionId=eWd9oM7vWyLhWR7kF) myself, I can tell you how I approached it.

First, a helper method to handle the logic of deciding when to remove an element from a sequence:

```cs
private static bool removeElement(IEnumerable<int> sequence, int i) {
    // This method handles the logic for determining whether to remove an element from a sequence of integers.
    // Initialize the return variable and declare some useful element aliases.
    bool removeElement = false;
    int c = sequence.ElementAt(i), p = sequence.ElementAtOrDefault(i - 1), n = sequence.ElementAtOrDefault(i + 1);

    // Remove the first element if and only if it is greater than or equal to the next element.
    if      (i == 0)                      removeElement = (c >= n);
    // Remove the last element if and only if it is less than or equal to the previous element.
    else if (i == (sequence.Count() - 1)) removeElement = (c <= p);
    // Removal logic for an element somewhere in the middle of the sequence:
    else {
        // If the current element is greater than the previous element...
        // ...and the current element is less than the next element, then do not remove the current element.
        if (c > p && c < n) removeElement = false;
        // If the current element is greater than or equal to the next element, then it might need to be removed.
        else if (c > p && c >= n) {
            removeElement = true;

            // Handle edge case for test 19.
            // If the current element is the next-to-last element...
            // ...and the only reason it's being considered for removal is because it is less than the last element...
            // ...then skip it and remove the last element instead.
            if (i == (sequence.Count() - 2)) removeElement = false;

            // Handle edge case for test 16.
            // If the current element occurs before the next-to-last element...
            if (i < (sequence.Count() - 2))
                // ...and both the current and next elements are less than the following element...
                // ...then skip the current element and remove the next one instead.
                if (n < sequence.ElementAt(i + 2) && c < sequence.ElementAt(i + 2)) removeElement = false;
        // Otherwise, remove the current element.
        } else removeElement = true;
    }

    return removeElement;
}
```

Then I wrote two versions of the main method: one using LINQ, and one without.

LINQ version:

```cs
bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    // Eliminate the most trivial cases first.
    if      (sequence.Length <= 2)                                        return true;
    else if (sequence.SequenceEqual(sequence.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))) return true;
    else {
        // Get the index of the first element that should be removed from the sequence.
        int index = Enumerable.Range(0, sequence.Length).First(x => removeElement(sequence, x));
        // Remove that element from the sequence.
        sequence = sequence.Where((x, i) => i != index).ToArray();
    }

    // Return whether or not the remaining sequence is strictly increasing.
    return sequence.SequenceEqual(sequence.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x));
}
```

Non-LINQ version:

```cs
bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    // Eliminate the most trivial cases.
    if (sequence.Length <= 2) return true;
    // Make a copy of the input array in the form of a List collection.
    var initSequence = new List<int>(sequence);
    // Iterate through the List.
    for (int i = 0; i < initSequence.Count; i++) {
        // If the current element needs to be removed from the List, remove it.
        if (removeElement(initSequence, i)) {
            initSequence.RemoveAt(i);
            // Now the entire sequence after the first removal must be strictly increasing.
            // If this is not the case, return false.
            for (int j = i; j < initSequence.Count; j++) {
                if (removeElement(initSequence, j)) return false;
            }

            break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Both variations pass all of the provided test cases:

```
38/38 tests passed.
Sample tests: 19/19
Hidden tests: 19/19
Score: 300/300
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version. It has similarities with [Peter Duniho's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3538012/peter-duniho) first [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42403833/11178549).

```
static bool AlmostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence)
{
    int problemIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        if (sequence[i] < sequence[i + 1])
            continue; // The elements i and i + 1 are in order
        if (problemIndex != -1)
            return false; // The sequence has more than one problems, so it cannot be fixed
        problemIndex = i; // This is the first problem found so far
    }
    if (problemIndex == -1)
        return true; // The sequence has no problems
    if (problemIndex == 0)
        return true; // The sequence can be fixed by removing the first element
    if (problemIndex == sequence.Length - 2)
        return true; // The sequence can be fixed by removing the last element
    if (sequence[problemIndex - 1] < sequence[problemIndex + 1])
        return true; // The sequence can be fixed by removing the (problemIndex) element
    if (sequence[problemIndex] < sequence[problemIndex + 2])
        return true; // The sequence can be fixed by removing the (problemIndex + 1) element
    return false; // The sequence cannot be fixed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have applied a recursive method:

```
public bool IsAlmostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence)
{
    if (sequence.Length <= 2)
        return true;
    return IsAlmostIncreasingSequenceRecursive(sequence, 0);
}

private bool IsAlmostIncreasingSequenceRecursive(int[] sequence, int seed)
{
    int count = seed;
    if (count > 1) //condition met: not almost
        return false;

    for (int i = 1; i < sequence.Length; i++)
    {
        if (sequence[i] <= sequence[i - 1])
        {
            if (i >= 2 && sequence[i - 2] >= sequence[i])
                sequence = RemoveAt(sequence, i);
            else
                sequence = RemoveAt(sequence, i - 1);

            return IsAlmostIncreasingSequenceRecursive(sequence, ++count);
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static int[] RemoveAt(int[] sequence, int index)
{
    for (int i = index; i < sequence.Length - 1; i++)
        sequence[i] = sequence[i + 1];
    Array.Resize(ref sequence, sequence.Length - 1);

    return sequence;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Well I have seen many solutions but things were made complicated a bit so here is my short and precise solution for that particular c# code problem.

```
bool solution(int[] sequence) {
//if there is just one item return true
            if (sequence.Length <= 2) return true;
           
            //create list for sequence comparison, C# beauty
            List<int> newList = new List<int>();

            if (sequence.Length > 0)
            {
                newList = new List<int>(sequence);
            }
            //just check if array is already valid sequence
            if (sequence.SequenceEqual(newList.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))) return true;

            //count occurance of no sequence
            int noSecCount = 0;
            //for checking Gap 
            int lastGap = 0, thisGap = 0;
            for (int n = 0; n < sequence.Count() - 1; n++)
            {
                thisGap = sequence[n + 1] - sequence[n];
                //if current value is less then next one continue as array is in sequence by this point
                //if not less then next one we have a situation here to further digging
                if (!(sequence[n] < sequence[n + 1]))
                {
                    noSecCount++;
                    //if we found more than one occurance of no sequence numbers, this array is not in sequence
                    if (noSecCount > 1) return false;
                    switch (n)
                    {
                        case 0: //First item at index 0
                            lastGap = thisGap;
                            newList = new List<int>(sequence);
                            newList.RemoveAt(n);
                            if (newList.SequenceEqual(newList.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))) return true;
                            break;
                        default: //any other item above index 0
                            //just remove current item and check the sequence
                            newList = new List<int>(sequence);
                            newList.RemoveAt(n);
                            if (newList.SequenceEqual(newList.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))) return true;

                            //remove the next item and check the sequencce
                            newList = new List<int>(sequence);
                            newList.RemoveAt(n + 1);
                            if (newList.SequenceEqual(newList.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x))) return true;
                           
                            //if we reach here we need to check if gap between previous comparison and current one is same? if not we should quick as we find more then
                            //one out of sequence values.
                            if (thisGap != lastGap) return false;
                            lastGap = thisGap;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
           
            //if we reach here and there is only one item which is out of sequence, we can remove it and get the sequence
            return noSecCount == 1;

}
```

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for the help strangers! I was able to get all my tests to pass first by removing all the increment/decrement operators for simplicity and simplifying my logic. If the iterator element is greater than or equal to the next element, increment my erasedElements variable. If that variable is 1, we know we've only removed one element and satisfied the increasing sequence.

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] sequence) {
    int erasedElements = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sequence.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if(sequence[i] >= sequence[i+1])
        {
            erasedElements += 1;
        }
    }

    Console.Write(erasedElements);
    return (erasedElements == 1);   
}
```

All of the following sequences passed:

[1, 3, 2, 1]

[1, 3, 2]

[1, 4, 10, 4, 2]

[10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]

[0, -2, 5, 6]

[1, 1]

Comment: This will return true if the sequence is [1, 2, 3, 1, 2], which is not correct.

Comment: As noted, this is incorrect in a number of ways. First, having 0 "erased elements" should be fine (the problem states "at most", not "exactly one". Second, sequences requiring more than one deletion might only count one deletion with this algorithm. Other invalid sequences (i.e. which produce incorrect results) include `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }` and `{ 1, 10, -1, 2, 3 }`.