# Exceptional case on AlmostIncreasingSequence

Tags: c#, .net

I'm doing the [AlmostIncreasingSequence](https://wachino.github.io/codefights/codefights-arcade/codefights-arcade-intro/7_almostIncreasingSequence/README.html).
So far my code is looking like this:

```
bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] arr) 
{
    int removed = 0;
    if(arr.Length == 2) return true;
    if(arr.Length - arr.Distinct().Count() > 1) removed++;
    for(int i = arr.Length-1; i > 0 ; i--)
    {
        if(arr[i] <= arr[i-1]) removed++; 
    }
    return removed == 1;
}
```

There is, however, one single case that it doesn't work, it being the sequence: [40, 50, 60, 10, 20, 30]. Do you have any suggestion on how to solve this? I know there are [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42401721/checking-whether-a-sequence-of-integers-is-increasing) about this question here already, but I don't want simply to paste a working code and forget about it, I want to see if my implementation is valid and if I can adress cases like that without changing the code too much.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you just need to keep around the highest found so far, which is the problem with your current implementation.

Done with a `foreach` would look kind of like this

```
public static bool almostIncreasingSequence(int[] arr)
{
   var removed = 0;
   var highest = arr[0];

   foreach (var current in arr)
      if (current > highest) highest = current;
      else if (removed++ > 1) return false;

   return true;
}
```

<sub>***Disclaimer** : completely untested, and may be totally wrong*</sub>

Comment: The code works (you have to ommit the public static statements) but there are a few cases where it doesnt work since, well, if there is just a big number that can be removed but there are a lot of numbers after it (as in [10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]). Also, I like your idea on how to solve this, but do u think my idea is doomed?

Comment: @JoãoGabriel no you idea is fine, you just have to keep track of the largest or smallest number depending which way you are iterating. That solves the problem of consecutive groups